# Help me identify a game from Ubuntu app directory

Tags: games

I used to have Ubuntu as my main machine, and I remember playing a game from the app directory. I'm pretty sure it was one of the top games, but I can't find it online.

Here's what I remember about it:

- You ride in a spaceship
- you can fly to different planets and scan them
- I'm pretty sure the positions of the planets/stars would change periodically, so you'd have to keep track of that
- some planets have resources you might need
- you can use resources to upgrade your ship
- there's a bunch of different races, one of them is a bunch of frogs

I'm pretty sure it's not a text based game, but something like a 600x800 resolution game. If I remember correctly, the primary UI color was red.

I recently heard about Aurora 4x, and a lot of the game mechanics sound very similar. But the one I'm talking about isn't *as* in-depth, and definitely had a decent UI.

Can someone identify this?

Comment: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oolite/? When was this?

Comment: it wasn't that but it was in the related ones - it's Ur-Quan Masters! Thanks!